# Load config.yml from jar location if exits?

Tags: java, yaml, config

I have coded a little Config Class.
It all works perfectly fine but there comes my problem:
I use config.setString(bla bla bla)
and then config.save();
When i save my config it appears in the same location as my jar file is.
This is what i want to see. But when i reboot my program, my config will be loaded from the jar again. I want that the config will only be loaded from the jar itself, if the file doesnt exist in the same folder as the jar is. Else it should load the "saved file"...

Could you like give me a little code snipped for it?.. I Struggle for a long time now

This is how i load it currently:

```
 private void loadYaml(InputStream inputStream, Map<String, Object> target, String pathPrefix) throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            Map<String, Object> yamlConfig = yaml.load(reader);
            if (yamlConfig == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid YAML syntax");
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : yamlConfig.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                if (value instanceof Map) {
                    // Recursively process nested maps
                    String nestedPath = pathPrefix.isEmpty() ? key : pathPrefix + "." + key;
                    loadYaml(new ByteArrayInputStream(yaml.dump(value).getBytes()), target, nestedPath);
                } else {
                    // Construct the full path for this leaf value
                    String fullPath = pathPrefix.isEmpty() ? key : pathPrefix + "." + key;
                    // Store the value in the target map
                    target.put(fullPath, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void load(String filePath) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        String fileExtension = getFileExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.equals("yml") || fileExtension.equals("yaml")) {
            loadYaml(inputStream, config, "");
        } else {
            loadPlainText(inputStream);
        }
    }
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Then you need to test if the file is in the current directory first, else load from jar

Comment: Your load function currently only checks the classloader (inside the jar classpath). What have you tried to read the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior, you can modify the load method to check if the config file exists in the same folder as the jar file. If the file exists, load the config from the file, otherwise load it from the jar. Here's some code that demonstrates this:

```java
public void load(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File configFile = new File(fileName);
    if (configFile.exists()) {
        // If the config file exists, load it from the file
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFile)) {
            String fileExtension = getFileExtension(fileName);
            if (fileExtension.equals("yml") || fileExtension.equals("yaml")) {
                loadYaml(inputStream, config, "");
            } else {
                loadPlainText(inputStream);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // If the config file doesn't exist, load it from the jar
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        try (InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Config file not found: " + fileName);
            }
            String fileExtension = getFileExtension(fileName);
            if (fileExtension.equals("yml") || fileExtension.equals("yaml")) {
                loadYaml(inputStream, config, "");
            } else {
                loadPlainText(inputStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code checks if the file exists using the `File.exists()` method. If the file exists, it loads the config from the file using a `FileInputStream`. If the file doesn't exist, it loads the config from the jar using a `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` method.

Comment: *...you can modify the load method to check if the config file exists in the same folder as the jar file.* That really depends on the parameter `fileName`. If it contains no file separator char then it won't look in "the same folder as the jar". It will look in the *current directory* - something that could be quite different.

Comment: otoh, if it does contain file separator chars, i.e. you're instructed to look somewhere other than the current directory *and* when that "fileName" doesn't exist as a file, then using that as an argument to `getResourceX` might be quite inappropriate, since it requires a classloader url, *not* a file name